# How to handle items added to Attached Property of ObservableCollection type

Tags: wpf, uwp

I have a UWP project that uses MapControl, which is a sealed class - cant derive a new class from it.
Trying to make a bindable Attached Property, which would have access to MapControl.Children.
The problem is that it only works when I set ViewModel's collection, but not when I add a new element to that collection:

```
// Works fine
this.MapChildrenExtCollection = new ObservableCollection<MapChildElement>();

// Nothing happens
this.MapChildrenExtCollection.Add(new MapChildElement());
```

Heres my code for the Attached Property:

```
namespace UWPMap.Extensions
{
    public class MapControlExt : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenExtProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ChildrenExt",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<MapChildElement>),
            typeof(MapControlExt),
            new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<MapChildElement>(), ChildrenExtPropertyChanged));

        public ObservableCollection<MapChildElement> ChildrenExt
        {
            get { return (ObservableCollection<MapChildElement>)GetValue(ChildrenExtProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildrenExtProperty, value); }
        }

        public static void SetChildrenExt(UIElement element, ObservableCollection<MapChildElement> value)
        {
            element.SetValue(ChildrenExtProperty, value);
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<MapChildElement> GetChildrenExt(UIElement element)
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<MapChildElement>)element.GetValue(ChildrenExtProperty);
        }

        private static void ChildrenExtPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (MapControl)obj;
            var oldCollection = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            var newCollection = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

            if (oldCollection != null)
            {
                oldCollection.CollectionChanged -= Extensions.MapControlExt.ChildrenExtCollectionChanged;
            }

            if (newCollection != null)
            {
                oldCollection.CollectionChanged += Extensions.MapControlExt.ChildrenExtCollectionChanged;
            }

            ManageChildrenExt();
        }

        static void ChildrenExtCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ManageChildrenExt();
        }

        static private void ManageChildrenExt()
        {
            // Access MapControl.Children here
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="MyMap"
                 ext:MapControlExt.ChildrenExt="{x:Bind Path=MapChildrenExtCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: As a note, for an attached property you should call RegisterAttached instead of Register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not adding the event handler to the new collection and using `oldCollection` variable by mistake.

The following snippet:

```
if (newCollection != null)
{
    oldCollection.CollectionChanged += //here you have oldCollection by mistake
       Extensions.MapControlExt.ChildrenExtCollectionChanged;
}
```

Should be:

```
if (newCollection != null)
{
    newCollection.CollectionChanged += 
       Extensions.MapControlExt.ChildrenExtCollectionChanged;
}
```

Comment: You're right, my fault ... trying to delete this question now

Comment: But then -is it possible to access MapControl in ManageChildrenExt() upon adding a single element? ChildrenExtCollectionChanged args are: Collection and NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs

Comment: However, I suggest to post this as a new question, because it really is a different matter than the original.